# Calculate probabilities to win an a slot machine

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to calculate the probability to win in a slot machine. 
Return-to-Player is 96%.
I have used the sum of the Binomial Coefficient to calculate it.

Since Return to Player is 96%, I make the assumption that the chances to win is 48% given that you're paid 1:1. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

To win money over 1000 spins you need to win at least 501 of them.

My equation:

$$ \sum \left(\,^nC_r (0.48^X)(1-0.48)^{y-x},x,1000,501\right) = 0.0927$$

which is about 9.3%

In 9.3% of the cases, the player would have more money than he started with after 1000 spins.

Is this the correct way to do it?

**How would I instead calculate the probability that he has 75% left of what he started with?**

Comment: I have attempted to type out your equation in MathJax, however I'm not sure I understand exactly what you meant. take a look and edit it if I have done it wrong :)

Comment: Hey Lioness, what part is it you don't understand? What I want to achieve or the equation as such?

Comment: The equation, why does it have commas in it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be an amount that the player started with.

He has 75% left thus after the 1000 spins he have to lose $0.25 N$. If $k$ is the number of wins then $k-(1000-k)=-0.25 N \rightarrow k = 500 - 0.125 N $ (let's assume that $N$ is such that $k \in \mathbb{N}$).

Assuming that $N>=1000$ then
\begin{equation}
P(X=k) = {1000 \choose k } 0.48^k(1-0.48)^{1000-k}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you, I realized that my math skills are not what they once there. 
If we add numbers to equation it might be easier to follow your solution for me. 

Let's say start budget 10 000. 
Each bet is 10.
What is then the probability to have 7500 left after 1000 spins?

Comment: Such player has to win $375$ times out of $1000$ (Wins 3750, loses 6250, net loss = $6250-3750 = 2500$). $P = {1000 \choose 375} 0.48^{375}0.52^{625} \simeq 4.97 * 10^{-12}$

Comment: The problem with this calculation is that 4.97*10^-12 is zero. That would mean that the chances to have at least 75% left of your money is 100%. In most cases they have already lost their money in 1000 spins. There is something that doesn't add up.

Comment: Yes, there is. Notice that in your reply it is first time that you wrote "at least 75%". In your post and in comments you wrote 75% left (exactly 7500) which for given parameters is quite unlikely (as you spotted). You want $P(X=7500)$ or $P(X\geq 7500)$?

Comment: You're right Vermator! How would it be when we calculated it with at least 75%?

Comment: It is binomial distribution with $p=0.48$ and $N=1000$. $1-F(374) \simeq 1$